# Code for printing vowels and consonants separately not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

Input a string. Then perform::
Each letter is printed on a new line.
Then the vowels are printed in the same order as they appeared in .
Then the consonants are printed in the same order as they appeared in

Sample Input

```
javascriptloops
```

Sample Output

```
a
a
i
o
o
j
v
s
c
r
p
t
l
p
s
```

here is what i did

```js
let a = [];
let b = [];
vowelsAndConsonants("javascriptloops");

function vowelsAndConsonants(s) {
  let i;
  let k = 0,
    j = 0;
  s.trim();
  s.toLowerCase();
  for (i = 0; i <= s.length; i++) {
    if (s.charAt(i) === "a" || s.charAt(i) === "e" || s.charAt(i) === "i" || s.charAt(i) === "o" || s.charAt(i) === "u") {
      a[k] = s.charAt(i);
      k++;
    } else {
      b[j] = s.charAt(j);
      j++;
    }
  }

}

for (let i = 0; i <= a.length; i++) {
  console.log(a[i]);
}
for (let i = 0; i <= b.length; i++) {
  console.log(b[i]);
}
```

Comment: `b[j] = s.charAt(j);` should be `b[j] = s.charAt(i);`

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Updated the code.

No need to keep and update `k` & `j`

What I did is if vowel is present the push it array `a` else for consonants push it to `b`

Also keep in mind that array starts with index 0, so you have to mention condition as `< array.length` instead of `<= array.length`

```js
let a = [];
let b = [];
vowelsAndConsonants("javascriptloops");

function vowelsAndConsonants(s) {
  s.trim();
  s.toLowerCase();
  for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (s.charAt(i) === "a" || s.charAt(i) === "e" || s.charAt(i) === "i" || s.charAt(i) === "o" || s.charAt(i) === "u") {
      a.push(s.charAt(i));
    } else {
      b.push(s.charAt(i));
    }
  }

}

for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  console.log(a[i]);
}
for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
  console.log(b[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is using regular expression to match vowels and consonants, and then print each of them.

> Below is the working code snippet:

```
        function vowelsAndConsonants(s) {
            var vw =s.match(/[aeiouAEIOU]+?/g); //regular expression to match vowels
            var con=s.match(/[^aeiouAEIOU]+?/g); //regular expression to not match vowels, ie. to match consonants
            printOnConsole(vw); //print vowels
            printOnConsole(con); //print consonants
       }

      //function to print values on console.
       function printOnConsole(arrPrint){
         for(var i=0;i<arrPrint.length;i++){
            console.log(arrPrint[i]);
          } 
       }
```